# How does "or" short-circuiting and error work in Go?

Tags: go

```
if true || 0/0 == 0 {
    print()
}
```

If the first parameter is true, then the 0/0 wouldn't be evaluated.

Why does this return a DIVIDE BY ZERO error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The divide by zero here is a compiler error, not a runtime error. Shortcutting only applies at runtime. If you change it to `0/x` where `x` is set to zero, you won't get the error:

```
var x = 0

if true || 0/x == 0 {
    print()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/7E9MMqUbnQm